# Returning a list in in sql to a list type

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to use linq query to set all items in x to a list

I'm getting the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.collection.generic.List

and the same for int

```
public List<AuthorityLevelList> GetUserAuthLevelListnew()
{
        try
        {
            return db.ap_GetAuthorityLevelList()
                .Select(c => new AuthorityLevelList{ UserAuthorityLevel2 = c.UserAuthorityLevel.ToList() , ID = c.ID  })
                .ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}

public partial class AuthorityLevelList
{
        public List<int> ID { get; set; }
        public List<string> UserAuthorityLevel2 { get; set; }
}
```

The main question is how do I set the linq to return a list and not just a string, I want all items from table column x in list UserAuthorityLevel2 and the the same for the int ID's

Please help

Comment: so; can I check - you want to return a **single** `AuthorityLevelList` instance with all the items, yes?

Comment: What is type of `ap_GetAuthorityLevelList()` return value?

Comment: return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<ap_GetUserAuthorityLevelListItems_Result>("ap_GetUserAuthorityLevelListItems");

Comment: @Marc Gravell Yes I would like the 'AuthorityLevelList' to contain all items for authlevels. and the Id to have a list of ID's

Comment: btw; don't `try`/`catch` if the only thing you are going to do is to `throw` or `throw ex;` - that is entirely pointless

Comment: yes i know iv not implanted any real catches yet

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a single `AuthorityLevelList` instance, not a `List<AuthorityLevelList>`; then:

```
var raw = db.ap_GetAuthorityLevelList();

return new AuthorityLevelList {
   ID = raw.Select(x => x.ID).ToList(),
   UserAuthorityLevel2 = raw.Select(x => x.UserAuthorityLevel).ToList(),
};
```

Comment: with this method I am string getting is this because of my public list? having a return type of a list?

Comment: don't worry it was that issue, Thanks

Comment: actually if I remove that and have just 'public AuthorityLevelList GetUserAuthLevelListnew()' I get the same error and then if I try to return the 'return new List<UserAuthorityLevelListItems>' the ID and AuthLevel error in the same way, is this because its a list within a list?

Comment: what new `List<UserAuthorityLevelListItems>` ? your question doesn't even mention `UserAuthorityLevelListItems`

Comment: sorry I mean List<AuthorityLevelList>

Comment: @Mikey yeah, I didn't create a `List<AuthorityLevelList>` either. It seems to me that if you are having the lists internally, you only need to return a single `AuthorityLevelList`, not a `List<>` of them; so: change the return type to `AuthorityLevelList`, IMO